# Rest API automation testing

Tags: rest-api, java

I'm currently working on an automation project with Salesforce and I need to fetch data from the backend. What I need is some guidance on how to create an RestAPI end point so from my java project I can query the data I need.

Comment: Just to make things absolutely clear, are you looking to create a REST API for your the Java portion of your solution? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: If you are referring "back end" as the salesforce backend then i suggest take a look at the rest resource.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm

Comment: I need to create the rest API for Salesforce, I know how to create the connection for java but I need to create the end point in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done via Connected App in Salesforce which will have a consumer key and secret to get the token to have access from End

Comment: refer to this article for quick help https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/salesforce-rest-api-setup-shiva-prakash-pokala/